# redux container component without a class

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following container component

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LoginStatus from './LoginStatus';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    displayName: state.displayName
});

// filterTodo => filterTodo !== todo

const LoginStatusContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(LoginStatus);

export default LoginStatusContainer;
```

I want to provide a render method for this component (container component) and pass in some parameters to the LoginStatus component.  I also want to do this without using Classes (extends React.Component).  Is this possible, or do I have to include a class here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your container component can absolutely be a [stateless component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html):

```
const LoginStatusContainer = (props) => {
  return (
    <LoginStatus
      myPprop={true}
      otherProp={"foo"}
    />
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginStatusContainer);
```